# How to get data from 2 entities in MVC ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application and using razor syntax. I have used model first method.

I have two entities, Customer and Lead. Lead is inherited from Customer.

When IsActive property is true then Customer treated as a Lead, otherwise it will be a customer.

Please check edmx file image.

[image]

Now, In regular entities we just deal with single entity and single table.
In this case how can I handle , Save and Load process. beacuse I have to store and load the record from 2 tables of DB. 
Is Regular Index View will work here ?

Answer (score 0):

When using inheritance in the Entity Framework you will have a single `DbSet` on your `DbContext` that exposes your hierarchy. In your database you have several options for configuring your table structure. For example you can use:

- Table per Hierarchy
- Table per Type
- Table per Concrete type

(See this blog for a nice explanation: [Inheritance in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/03/15/inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

In your queries however, you don't have to think about this. Your queries will have the following structure:

```
var leads = from l in dbcontext.Leads.OfType<Customer>()
            select l;
```

The [OfType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) filters your collection to a subtype in your hierarchy. If you skip the `OfType` you will get both customers and leads in your resulting query.

Comment: If you see my entity structure U will know that, Customer is the base entity and lead is inherited entity.Now both Customer and Leads objects will take records from same table Customer. Now,  I have added field called IsActive to differentiate between these two. If IsActive is True then that customer will be treated as lead. Now the issue is how to get the leads in Index View ? 
`var leads = from l in db.Customers.OfType<Lead>()
                        select l;
            return View(leads.ToList());` this query returning 0 records.

Comment: If your IsActive column should be used by EF to map your inheritance hierarchy, it shouldn't show up in your designer. How have you mapped your hierarchy?

Comment: Please go through this question, I have posted this question. before this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618727/how-to-deal-with-inherited-entity-in-ef-and-mvc-app